# How to present UIViewController from content ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I got menuVC that contain from composition of other VC's, one of this is loginViewController, how to go to loginViewController from menuVC? Or it is a best way to load VC from method? My code :

```
MenuViewController * menuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuViewController"];
 [menuViewController presentViewController:menuViewController.loginViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I can do it like this:

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
MenuViewController * menuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuViewController"];
[menuViewController showLoginViewController];
```

with error: Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: you have to navigate to either one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot present a view controller modally when the app has not been presented in view yet. You can present it in the viewDidAppear method of menu view controller.  You will have to do it in viewDidAppear and not in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear as the view that you are presenting it on is not in the current window hierarchy, basically the same issue that you are having by doing it in the app delegate.  If you want it already shown when the app launches just choose set animated to NO. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: So, if I want to have menuVC and load from it other VC during all app runtime, what should I do?

Comment: If you are trying to show the login screen initially on top of the menu view controller just have a boolean in menu view controller isLogged in that way once you are logged in the set it to true so the view controller will not show every time the viewAppears. inside menu view controller call [self.view presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil]; in viewDidAppear and it will be shown first at runtime

Comment: I used this approach, but now I run my loginVC from AppDelegate only if user not saved in Keychain or from menuVC if user logout. I need some help with architecture, my app will contain a menuVC, other VC, and some not VC classes. I want to run all VC from menu VC or with it delegate with methods, also if there is no such VC in menu I will run it from menuVC . Am I right?

Comment: thats really not a problem. Just make a global boolean like I said before in your menuVC and in your app delegate inside applicationDidFinishLaunching just set the boolean (isLoggedIn) to YES to not show it and NO to show it. Inside the app delegate applicationDidFinishLaunching will be called before your menuVC's viewDidAppear gets called.